# Javascript 'x days ago' to datetime

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have strings that show a date in the following format:

```
x minutes/hours/days/months/years ago
```

I need to parse that to a datetime format like `2021-08-05T09:44:19.014Z` using javascript / nodejs.

It seems `momentjs` can't do it.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sorry I meant javascript/nodejs not python...

Comment: simple reg exp, match it, do the math....

Comment: Could you post an example? What do you have and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is.

Here's a simple implementation I whipped up that turns a string such as "10 hour" (and coincidentally "10 hours ago" too, since the regexp is unanchored on the other end) into a number of seconds.

You can then subtract that number of seconds from the current date, or however you like to deal with things.

```
const multipliers = {
  second: 1,
  minute: 60,
  hour: 60 * 60,
  day: 60 * 60 * 24,
  month: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  year: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
};

function parseTextDuration(s) {
  var m = /^(.+)\s*(second|minute|hour|day|month|year)/i.exec(s);
  if (!m) throw new Error("invalid string");
  const [, mulStr, unit] = m;
  const mul = parseFloat(mulStr);
  if (isNaN(mul)) throw new Error("invalid number");
  const unitMul = multipliers[unit.toLowerCase()];
  if (!unitMul) throw new Error("invalid unit");
  return mul * unitMul;
}
```

Example:

```
> console.log(parseTextDuration("10 months"));
25920000
> console.log(parseTextDuration("3 minutes ago"));
180
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion

```js
const methods = {
  minutes: (d,mins) => d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - mins),
  hours: (d,hours) => d.setHours(d.getHours() - hours),
  days: (d,days) => d.setDate(d.getDate() - days),
  months: (d,months) => d.setDate(d.getMonth() - months),
  years: (d,years) => d.setDate(d.getMonth() - years)
}
const ago = str => {
  const d = new Date()
  let [_,howmany, scale] = [...str.match(/(\d+) (\w+)\b/)]
  scale = scale.endsWith("s") ? scale : `${scale}s`
  return new Date(methods[scale](d,howmany));
}

const str = "10 minutes ago"

console.log(ago(str))
```

Comment: There seem to be some copy-paste errors. `setDate()` * 3, `getMonth()` * 2?